# Display multiple products on same page in Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I have a module that responds to an Ajax request. I'm attempting to have it render multiple products and get the resulting HTML. My controller is code is below. I hard coded the IDs for testing purposes.

$id = 52986;

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProduct($id, $this);
    $this->loadLayout();
    $output[] = $this->getLayout()->getOutput();
    Mage::unregister('current_product');
    Mage::unregister('product');
}
print_r($output);
```

I assumed each product rendering in a foreach would independently render each one (i.e. A 'new' layout would be created for each render). Clearly I don't fully understand how the layout system works. Thus I have two questions.

1) How can I get the rendered HTML of each product?

2) Why doesn't rendering the layout work the way I expect it to?

For related info, this is the layout XML I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <shopthelook_ajax_index>
        <update handle="catalog_product_view" />
            <remove name="html_calendar" />
            <reference name="root" output="toHtml">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>shopthelook/wrapper.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="product.info">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="product.info.media">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/media.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="product.info.options.configurable">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
    </shopthelook_ajax_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, update your layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <shopthelook_ajax_index>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="shopthelook_ajax/response" template="shopthelook_ajax/response.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </shopthelook_ajax_index>
</layout>
```

It basically tells Magento to add new output (block) to your controller. Now you need to create this block class in your module (app/code/local/Shopthelook/Ajax/Block/Response.php):

```
class Shopthelook_Ajax_Block_Response
extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $productIds = array(52986, 52987, 52988);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

and create a template file (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/shopthelook_ajax/response.phtml:

```
<?php $_collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<ul class="products">
<?php foreach ($_collection as $_product) { ?>
    <li>
        <span class="product-name"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></span>
        ...
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

After this just update your controller to render its layout:

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

The action will load merged layout xml file and find the handles depending on your module/controller/action name (in your case shopthelook_ajax_index). Then it will create and render your block using selected template. In the template getCollection method is called which creates a collection of selected products.

Not sure if the code is 100% correct because I can't test it at the moment but the architecture & principles should be OK.

Comment: This gets me much closer! I really need to use the product.info block, but the entire catalog module is built to deal with one product at a time. Essentially what I'm trying to do is have it load layout, render HTML, and repeat.

Comment: The catalog.product (catalog/product_view) block loads product model from global registry (Mage::registry('product')). To render the block on one page multiple times you would need to register product model to the global registry and after rendering the block deregister it and register another product model again. But I definitely can't recommend this approach to you because the product_view block does another things beyond the scope of just rendering product data (for example it sets page title and meta information). Better approach is to create custom block to render product data.